# Alexa::ResponseError when using Alexa gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am using [Alexa gem](https://github.com/morgoth/alexa) to use the UrlInfo webservice of Alexa web information service. I signed up for the AWIS service and obtained secret_key_id and secret_access_key.

Here is my code

```
@client = Alexa::Client.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWIS_KEY_ID'], secret_access_key: ENV['AWIS_ACESS_KEY'])
url_info = @client.url_info(url: params[:alexa_rank][:given_url])
```

but I am getting

> Alexa::ResponseError (AWS was not able to validate the provided access
>   credentials):

What am i doing  wrong? Please help

Comment: Are you sure the env variables are present? are you sure the params are present?

Comment: yes, In my rails console I can see my env variables as well as params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that Amazon could not verify the  credit card details I added for my AWS account due to my bank's security policy.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because my reputation is too low so I'm posting what I think might be an answer. [The code](https://github.com/morgoth/alexa/blob/b5156c73dacc773758e6442a0473c93a8440412c/lib/alexa/connection.rb#L39) raises a general error telling you that Amazon is responding with an access credentials error, which could mean a range of things. I'm thinking that this might be because something went wrong when you were setting up your skill in the developer console, because Alexa doesn't automatically check for access keys to communicate with a server, if that's what your aim is.

If you haven't already, you'll need to do two things.

1. Get an https forwarding service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) running along with your rails server.
2. Make a [self-signed certificate](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/testing-an-alexa-skill#create-a-private-key-and-self-signed-certificate-for-testing) (or alternatively purchase one), and copy+paste the body of your certificate.pem file into the SSL section of the skill in the developer console after clicking the "self-signed" button.

After this, I'd recommend commenting out that instance and seeing if your Alexa instance is communicating with your server. Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction.